# How to use numpy in matrices iterations like Matlab

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, controls

I am used to make my discrete time control systems simulations in Matlab and now I'm trying python and numpy.

So, my code bellow is working, but I would like to iterate over the numpy vector instead appending values into a list. Is it possible?

In other words, instead of using

```
xl.append(xt)
ul.append(uc)
```

I would like to use some Matlab equivalent like x[:, k+1] = np.dot(Ad, x[:, k]) + Bd*uc, but it's not working on my code. If I do that, instead of obtaining a two line column vector that is the expected, I got a 2x2 matrix and an error.

Another question: Why it's neccessary to use plt.plot(tk, u[:, 0], label='u') instead plt.plot(tk, u, label='u') ?

```
from control.matlab import *

import math
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Ts = 0.1

N = 50

#x = np.zeros((2, N+1))
tk = np.zeros(N)
u = np.zeros(N)

v = np.random.randn(N)/86.6 #% measurement noise


wn = 1.12
wn2 = pow(wn, 2)

A = [[0, 1], [-1.5, -1.4]]
B = [[0], [1.5]]
C = [[1, 0]]
D = 0


# Control gains
K = np.array([2.64, 3.41071429])

# Now build a feedback with control law u = -K*x
Ad = np.eye(2) + np.multiply(A, Ts)
Bd = np.multiply(B, Ts)
Cd = C

xt = [[1.0], [0.12]]   # initial states
xl = []
ul = []

for k in range(0, N):
    tk[k] = k*Ts
    uc = -K.dot(xt)
    xt = np.dot(Ad, xt) + Bd*uc
    
    xt[1, 0] += v[k]
    
    xl.append(xt)
    ul.append(uc)
    
x = np.array(xl)
u = np.array(ul)

#x = np.delete(x, N, 1) # delete the last position of x

#s = TransferFunction.s
#Gs  = wn2/(s**2 + 0*s + wn2) # This is the KF solution
#yout, T = step(Gs)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 7)

plt.figure()
#plt.plot(T, yout, label='Open loop')
plt.plot(tk, x[:, 0], label='x_0')
plt.plot(tk, x[:, 1], label='x_1')
plt.plot(tk, u[:, 0], label='u')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Pendulum ex. 7.14 Franklin book')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('amp.')
plt.show()
```

what I want is the code like this:

```
from control.matlab import *

import math
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


Ts = 0.1

N = 50

x = np.zeros((2, N+1))
tk = np.zeros(N)
u = np.zeros(N)

v = np.random.randn(N)/86.6 #% measurement noise


wn = 1.12
wn2 = pow(wn, 2)

A = [[0, 1], [-1.5, -1.4]]
B = [[0], [1.5]]
C = [[1, 0]]
D = 0


# Control gains
K = np.array([2.64, 3.41071429])

# Now build a feedback with control law u = -K*x
Ad = np.eye(2) + np.multiply(A, Ts)
Bd = np.multiply(B, Ts)
Cd = C


for k in range(0, N):
    tk[k] = k*Ts
    u[k] = -K.dot(x[:, k])

    x[1, k] += v[k]
    x[:, k+1] = np.dot(Ad, x[:, k]) + Bd*u[k]
    

x = np.delete(x, N, 1) # delete the last position of x

#s = TransferFunction.s
#Gs  = wn2/(s**2 + 0*s + wn2) # This is the KF solution
#yout, T = step(Gs)

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10, 7)

plt.figure()
#plt.plot(T, yout, label='Open loop')
plt.plot(tk, x[:, 0], label='x_0')
plt.plot(tk, x[:, 1], label='x_1')
plt.plot(tk, u[:, 0], label='u')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Pendulum ex. 7.14 Franklin book')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('amp.')
plt.show()
```

But it results in a following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ ... \np_matrices_v1.py", line 46, in <module>
    x[:, k+1] = np.dot(Ad, x[:, k]) + Bd*u[k]
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2) into shape (2,)
```

Comment: You have your answer in your code: `u = np.zeros(N)`. Preallocate `xl`, `ul` in a similar way

Comment: I added one more code section on my question to better clarify what is happening.

Comment: Right, but the error you are getting, you'd also get in MATLAB, it has nothing to do with the language. You are trying to put a 2x2 matrix into a 2x1 vector.  What do you think `np.dot(Ad, x[:, k])` should be? what it is in size? and `Bd`? are you accidental using automatic broadcasting?

Comment: It works in Matlab, as it works in the first code: Firs I multiply a 2x2 matrix (Ad) by a 2x1 vector (x[:, k]) and it results in a 2x1 vector that is summed to a 2x1 vector resulting of Bd*u. In second code if you do only the first part, that is, x[:, k+1] = np.dot(Ad, x[:, k]), you'll got the right answer, a 2x1 vector. But, if you sum it to Bd*u[k] (another 2x1 vector) it results in a 2x2 matriz, instead of a 2x1 vector as it should be. I don't know anything about broadcasting, I'll google it.

Comment: I have no Idea why, but I tried x[:, [k+1]] = Ad.dot(x[:, [k]]) + Bd*u[k] instead of x[:, k+1] = Ad.dot(x[:, k]) + Bd*u[k] and it is working now.

Comment: Its because one of them is 2x1 while the other one is 1x2. That is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [248]: A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])
     ...: x = np.array([[0.5], [2.0]])

In [249]: A.shape, x.shape
Out[249]: ((2, 2), (2, 1))

In [250]: y = A.dot(x)
In [251]: y.shape
Out[251]: (2, 1)
```

Note the shapes.  `x` is (2,1), and as a result `y` is too.  `y` can be assigned to a (2,1) slot, but not a (2,) shape.

```
In [252]: xa = np.zeros((2,5),int)
In [253]: xa
Out[253]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [254]: xa[:,2]
Out[254]: array([0, 0])     # (2,) shape

In [255]: xa[:,[2]]
Out[255]: 
array([[0],                 # (2,1) shape
       [0]])
```

In contrast to MATLAB `numpy` arrays can be 1d, e.g. (2,).  Also leading dimensions are the outermost, as opposed to trailing.  MATLAB readily reduces a (2,3,1) shape to (2,3), but a (2,1,1) only becomes (2,1).

`broadcasting` the way `numpy` uses arrays that can differ in shape.  The two basic rules are that

```
 - leading size 1 dimensions can added automatically to match
 - size 1 dimensions can be adjusted to match
```

Thus a (2,) can become a (1,2).

If you remove the inner [] from `x`, you get a 1d array:

```
In [256]: x = np.array([0.5, 2.0])    
In [257]: x.shape
Out[257]: (2,)    
In [258]: A.dot(x)
Out[258]: array([4.5, 7. ])     # (2,) shape
```

This can then be assigned to a row of `xa`: `xa[:,2] = A.dot(x)`

`reshape` and `ravel` can be used to remove dimensions.  Also indexing `A.dot(x)[:,0]`

Comment: I'm working on your explanation. By the way, what is the difference between (2,1) and (2,)? Aren't both a two line one column vector?

Comment: In MATLAB nothing has the size (2), just 1 dimension.  In `numpy` terms a MATLAB "vector" is either (2,1) or (1,2) size.  A `numpy` (2,) has just 1 dimension (the comma is part of the one element tuple display).  Because of broadcasting a (2,) array is more like a (1,2) than a (2,1).  The displays try to clearly show the differences with brackets.  You won't find "row vector" or "column vector" in `numpy` documentation.  Those are just names that roughly map on to linear-algebra concepts, but aren't formally part of the `numpy` definition.  `numpy` is more general.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but if you try:

```
A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])

x = np.array([[0.5], [2.0]])

y = A.dot(x)
print(y)
xa = np.zeros((2, 10))
xa[:, 2] = A.dot(x)
```

You'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\eletr\.spyder-py3\temp.py", line 19, in <module>
    xa[:, 2] = A.dot(x)
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,1) into shape (2,)
```

But if you do:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])

x = np.array([[0.5], [2.0]])

y = A.dot(x)
print(y)
xa = np.zeros((2, 10))
# xa[:, 2] = A.dot(x)
xa[:, [2]] = A.dot(x)
print(xa)
```

You'll get the correct answer:

```
[[4.5]
 [7. ]]
[[0.  0.  4.5 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]
 [0.  0.  7.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. ]]
```

Can anyone explain it?